# The Kubelet Pod Lifecycle Event Generator has a 99th percentile duration of 10 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have multiple clusters in AWS (Managed by AWS - EKS). Some nodes generate following alerts  (each node is m6i.xlarge, 4 CPU, 16GB, running 5.4.156-83.273.amzn2.x86_64, kubelet version v1.21.5-eks-bc4871b)

```
The Kubelet Pod Lifecycle Event Generator has a 99th percentile duration of 10 seconds
```

Other nodes from same cluster continue to work fine.  The node is small (16GB, 4 CPU), but does not have any real load. (less than  .6  when I noticed one such alert). Alert did come from multiple clusters. Number of pods reached about 70 when alert came.

The /var/log/messages from the node has tons of message similar to below

```
Feb 21 04:53:39 ip-10-11-19-219.prod.us-east-1.xxxxx  kubelet[3394]: I0221 04:53:39.904698    3394 kubelet.go:1973] "SyncLoop (PLEG): event for pod" pod="zcr-aqua/scan-configauditreport-fd9bd5d4b-rc6zm" event=&{ID:0731658f-5eeb-412f-b85a-4a16f1a298b6 Type:ContainerStarted Data:9adeeeb232ff8ed47a160ee2894f6537dd433e4a1f3321e3778baf0d68cd92f0}
```

Is it possible that pods from one bad job (zcr-aqua/scan-configauditreport*) can create this situation and cause alert?  All messages in kubelet log has this name

(There are some PLEG related observations in https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/11/13/pod-lifecycle-event-generator-understanding-the-pleg-is-not-healthy-issue-in-kubernetes#conclusions , did not appear to be applicable in this case)

Comment: Can you please specify which exact instance size is used for that node? Also some more details about application you're concerned about - what image is used? How many replicas does it have? Is it installed using operator or differently?

Comment: done. cluster is managed by aws.

Comment: Thank you. What about the application setup? Operator or manually installed? Some settings? At least to understand what can be wrong or its behaviour if it spans hundreds pods. Like with [airflow](https://coding-stream-of-consciousness.com/2021/01/04/kubernetes-pleg-issues-lots-of-ephemeral-pods-airflow/), I guess you saw it as well.

Comment: thanks. I was hoping that less than hundred pod is no big number. Applications are installed by fleet .  I will try creating more pods on "good" node to see if anything comes out.